# No styles in Laravel 5 after "removing" public folder from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I need your help with Laravel 5. I use xampp if this matters. I have removed a public folder from URL by copying .htaccess file to the main directory of the site. Than i renamed a "server.php" file to "index.php". That FINALLY helps me to kick that annoying folder from URL. BUT, now I haven't any styles on the pages of that project.When I open them in browser I see pages of HTML without CSS. Can somebody help me in this? I wanted to post pictures to help u guys understand what I see, but i haven't enough reputation do that. Thanks.

Comment: try to open css link url in new tab. might be absolute and relative path issue. try to relative path.

Comment: can you show me, how you extending css to your html page? expecting code.

Comment: add the `/` in front of your paths or use the base tag. `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`

Comment: I would rethink what you are doing here. You should create a virtual host and then set the document root to your public folder.  This way the public folder isn't part of the URL and you aren't exposing all those additional files, and your asset helper functions will all still work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Don't rename your `server.php` to `index.php`. There is already an `index.php` inside your `public` directory. Rename it back to `server.php`, create a `.htaccess` file inside your root web directory, and paste this inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
</IfModule>
```

I've used this `.htaccess` for a while during local development, and it works just fine. Keep in mind for production you wouldn't want to do this.

You shouldn't need to change anything else. Let me know if it works!

---

Here's the `web.config` version as well for IIS development:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Move to index.php">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
         <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the exact answer (y)

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I made everything that you said.

Comment: Did you return the original `.htaccess` file to it's original location as well? This needs to be done.

Comment: Yes, of course. I return it. And now, when I type localhost/laravel it gives me this result: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7693:        when I type "localhost/laravel/public/" - it's ok.

Comment: Work perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Rename `server.php` to `index.php` and copy htaccess from public folder to root directory . Call css `{!! asset('public/css/all.css') !!}`, and add `'public/'` before your css file location.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Rename server.php to index.php and copy htaccess from public folder to
> root directory past this in mywebsit/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
</IfModule>
```